# meaning of "fit in"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Her four dark blue suits (one, again, is missing) are identical,
> describing, John thinks, a pathological affinity for regularity, the
> constant and true. An attempt to **fit in** that unavoidably calls
> attention to itself.

This is from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead.

I don't understand what "fit in" means in this context.

Answer (score 1):

To fit in means to act or look like the other people you associate with. In this case, by wearing a blue suit similar to those worn by her colleagues she hopes will make her look like them and be accepted.